# Jolt how to do this transform? Concat and set in array

Tags: json, jolt

I have an input like this

```
    {
    "employee": {
        "id": "123456",
        "firstName": "John",
        "prefFirstName": "Doe",
        "lastName": "John",
        "prefLastName": "John",
        "mgrFirstName": "Mitch",
        "mgrPrefFirstName": "Mitch",
        "mgrLastName": "McEvoy",
        "mgrPrefLastName": "McEvoy",
        "gmFirstName": "GMName",
        "gmPrefFirstName": "GMName",
        "gmLastName": "GMLastName",
        "gmPrefLastName": "GMLastName",
        "dirFirstName": "DirFirstName",
        "dirPrefFirstName": "DirFirstName",
        "dirLastName": "DirLastName",
        "dirPrefLastName": "DirLastName",

    }
}
```

Expected output should be like this, I can't figure out the fields in **bold**.

"managers" : [ {
    "chnl" : "eml",
    **"nm": "Mitch McEvoy",
    “mgrlbl”: “Direct Manager”**
  }, {
    "chnl" : "eml",
    "eml" : "",
    **"nm": "GMName GMLastName",
    “mgrlbl”: “General Manager”**
  }, {
    "chnl" : "eml",
    "eml" : "",
    **"nm": "DirFirstName DirLastName",
    “mgrlbl”: “Director”**
  } ],
  "nhstdt" : "2020-11-23",
  "nhmob" : "",
  "nheml" : "empp@web.com",
  "mgreml" : [ "testttt@web.com", "testttt@web.com" ],
  "mgrchnl" : "email",
  "chnl" : "mob",
  "nhnm" : "Doe John",
  "mgrnm" : "Mitch McEvoy"

I have a transform like this but can't figure out how to get the desired output:

```
    [

  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "employee": {

        "prefFirstName": {
          "*": {
            "@1": "tmpFirstName",
            "@(2,prefLastName)": "tmpLastName"
          },
          "": {
            "@(2,firstName)": "tmpFirstName",
            "@(2,lastName)": "tmpLastName"
          }
        },
        "mgrPrefFirstName": {
          "*": {
            "@1": "tmpMgrFirstName",
            "@(2,mgrPrefLastName)": "tmpMgrLastName"
          },
          "": {
            "@(2,mgrFirstName)": "tmpMgrFirstName",
            "@(2,mgrLastName)": "tmpMgrLastName"
          }
        },

        "mgrName": "managers[0].nm",
        "mgrBusEmail": "managers[0].eml",
        "gmName": "managers[1].nm",
        "gmBusEmail": "managers[1].eml",
        "dirName": "managers[2].nm",
        "dirBusEmail": "managers[2].eml",
        "#eml": ["managers[0].chnl", "managers[1].chnl", "managers[2].chnl"]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "nhnm": "=concat(@(1,tmpFirstName),' ',@(1,tmpLastName))",
      "mgrnm": "=concat(@(1,tmpMgrFirstName),' ',@(1,tmpMgrLastName))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "mode": ["=toInteger", 0]
    }
  }
 ]
```

But I am not able to figure out how do I concatenate mgrFirstName and mgrLastName, gmFirstName and gmLastName, dirFirstName and dirLastName and after concatenation I need to set this in the array managers[0], managers[1] and managers[2] respectively.

I am not able to figure how do I modify an array which is in my shift spec after I concat the stirngs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the concatenation first with a `modify-default-beta` spec, then set the desired fields in the array. This should get you started:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "employee": {
        "mgrFullName": "=concat(@(1,mgrFirstName),' ',@(1,mgrLastName))",
        "gmFullName": "=concat(@(1,gmFirstName),' ',@(1,gmLastName))",
        "dirFullName": "=concat(@(1,dirFirstName),' ',@(1,dirLastName))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "employee": {
        "mgrFullName": "managers[0].nm",
        "mgrBusEmail": "managers[0].eml",
        "gmFullName": "managers[1].nm",
        "gmBusEmail": "managers[1].eml",
        "dirFullName": "managers[2].nm",
        "dirBusEmail": "managers[2].eml",
        "#eml": ["managers[0].chnl", "managers[1].chnl", "managers[2].chnl"],
        "#Direct Manager": "managers[0].mgrlbl",
        "#General Manager": "managers[1].mgrlbl",
        "#Director": "managers[2].mgrlbl"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thx @mattyb that works for me, however if you can help with a way I can also do an "if-else" kind of construct based on for eg: whether mgrPrefFirstName is present or not would be great. So if mgrPrefFirstName is present I use that or else I use mgrFirstName Thank you